# SQL RLIKE function Postcode Search

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand why the following query pulls through postcodes that I wouldn't expect.

SQL

```
Select distinct Postcode from tableA where like 'NE1%';
```

Shows 2 postcodes, all beginning with NE1

I've tried :-

```
Select distinct Postcode from tableA where rlike '^NE[0-1]%'
```

Shows many postcodes, including the 2 from above, such as NE27 0EZ - I'm assuming because it has a zero in the 2nd part of the postcode, but no idea why NE2 2NE appears !

My goal is to filter all postcodes that begin with an N (not NE) BUT only have a numeric as the next character - SQL only, not python or scala, as this filter forms 1 of many postcode filters (a large OR clause)

I would have thought for all postcodes beginning with a N that had a numeric as the next character would have worked :-

```
Select distinct Postcode from tableA where rlike 'N[0-9] %' or 'N[0-9][0-9] %' 



select distinct 'rlike' as Func , postcode from npex.npex where postcode rlike '^NE[0-1]*'
union
select distinct 'like', postcode from npex.npex where postcode like 'NE1%'
order by 1;

RESULTS
Func    postcode    
like    NE1 3BB    
like    NE12 1AB

rlike   NE27 0EZ    
rlike   NE6 2UT    
rlike   NE27 0LT    
rlike   NE12 1AB    
rlike   NE2 2NE    
rlike   NE3 4DT    
rlike   NE1 3BB
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` is not needed, otherwise you would be matching 0 or more of zeroes or ones.

```
select distinct postcode from npex.npex where postcode rlike '^NE[0-1]'
```

If you want to get those beginning with an N followed by a numeric, you can use

```
select distinct postcode from npex.npex where postcode rlike '^N[0-9]'
```